# Вызвать файл по абсолютному пути. html

Tags: apache, debian, файлы, веб-сервер

Есть сервер debian с apache2.2.22
Как вызывать отсюда `/var/www/folder/index.html` файл с расположением, например `/usr/src/file.txt` .
Если указываю `src='/usr/src/file.txt'`, то получаю ошибку `File does not exist: /var/www/folder/usr`

Comment: какой смысл вы вкладываете в слово «вызвать»? приведите, пожалуйста, пример «вызова».

Comment: Для примера должна загрузиться картинка src='/usr/src/pic.jpg'

Comment: Приведите код, который "вызывает".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы можете воспользоваться директивой [*alias*](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias). примерно так:

```
alias /usr/src/ /usr/src/
```

область применения — глобальная конфигурация всего сервера или конфигурация конкретного *virtualhost-а*.

Comment: через alias получилось, отлично. Но вот проблема при такой схеме не могу проверить существует ли файл. Попробовал сделать через симлинк, но че то с правами никак не получается.

Comment: *не могу проверить существует ли файл* — смело задавайте новый вопрос (кнопка в правом верхнем углу страницы). в качестве иллюстрации имеет смысл дать ссылку на *этот* вопрос.

Comment: спасибо. сам разобрался. Банальная невнимательность.